# MySQL Left join and missing rows

Tags: mysql

Well is there a way to make something like:

## table1

```
id -> PK
table1_id -> FK

id | name | table1_id
1,'test',NULL
2,'test2',NULL
3,'sub_val1',1
4,'sub_val2',1

select a.name
     , b.name 
from table1 a 
left join table1 b 
   on a.id=b.table1_id 
where a.table1_id is null;
```

this will return something like:

```
test,sub_val1
test,sub_val2
test2,NULL
```

I would like to it return something like:

```
test,NULL
test,sub_val1
test,sub_val2
test2,NULL
```

is there a way to do it?

Comment: What business rule are you trying to perform?  Are you looking for a way to guarantee the the result contains at least one row with a NULL value for the second column?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is:

```
select
    a.name,
    b.name
from
    table1 a
inner join
    table1 b on a.id = b.table1_id
where
    a.table1_id is null
union all
    select name, null from table1 where table1_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing but perhaps this is what you want:

```
select a.name as first_name
     , b.name as second_name
from table1 a 
left join table1 b 
   on a.id=b.table1_id 
where a.table1_id is null
union
select name as first_name
     , null as second_name
from table1  
where table1_id is null
order by first_name, second_name
```

You might need to specify the definition for the second column in the second operation (UNION).

Comment: inner join/union all version should perform slightly better than left join/union

Comment: @AlineGolvalve I don't see how to avoid a `UNION`; you need to include an extra row for the first condition.  And aguyngueran is correct; an `INNER JOIN` with `UNION ALL` will likely perform better and give the same result.